# Symbolize the selected feature

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am working on a plugin on QGis, i want to know if it possible to change the color of the border of the selected polygone, to appare differently from other polygones when i print the layout.
Cordialy

Answer (score 3):

There's a function called `is_selected()` : so you're able to use it to create **a rule-based symbology** to highlight the selected features in the layout *(or do you mean you want to achieve that programmatically ?)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  yeah exactly, i want that the current selection (polygone) appear differently than others when i am generating the layout.

Comment: but ... do u want to do it using **python** or is my answer fitting your needs ?

Comment: Yes i am using pyqgis to code a plugin on QGIS, so i am looking for if there is a possible to do it using Python Code

Comment: well you'are still able to programmaticaly create the rule-based symbology (some answers on gis.stack.exchange) and use the `is_selected` filtering condition ...

Comment: I found some answer but for pyqt 2, i am using pyqt 3, if you have any reference, i will be thankful if you share it